# When using gem browserify-rails, it does not reflect file changes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browserify, sprockets, browserify-rails

I want to develop javascript with CommonJS module in rails.
also I want to benefit from sprockets.
I found browserify-rails gem to solve that.
After tring, it seems to work well.
I could use module.
But when I change some files and refresh the browser, they are not reflected.
Do you have an idea to solve that ?

using package.json is below.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue (but not with browserify) which was solved after I removed turbo links from the project. Might be worth a try.

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, a bug was introduced with browserify-rails v2 and is present in 2.0.0 and 2.0.1. I [fixed the bug](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails/pull/121) in 2.0.2 which was just released. Please upgrade to 2.0.2 and clear the asset cache with:

`rake tmp:clear`

You may need to call it like `bundle exec rake tmp:clear`. If neither work, then from the project root, `rm -rf tmp/cache`. Then start Rails again and it should work as expected.